# Macro to remove duplicates from future event

Tags: excel, vba

The title is a bit vague but after explaining my problem...it may, at least, be in the parking lot of the ball park.

I use a mysql query that grabs monthly data that is exported into excel. From there, I copy/paste special this data onto one of the tabs on my template, which in turn is saved using a standard name (this will leave the template, with all the other macros, free to be used in the future). The template currently has 4 macros designed to do various things that the user gets their report by simply pressing a button.

The problem: I am trying to create a macro that would be on this template. The macro needed would copy data from an empty column (to eventually be populated using process in paragraph 2), paste it onto another 'working' tab, remove the header, sort and lastly remove duplicates. The macro gets hung up on the remove duplicates, as it apparently does not like empty columns.

Is this possible or am I stuck doing this process manually?

macro code:

```
Sub UpdateProcessor()
'
' UpdateProcessor Macro
'

'
    ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Position:=xlLast
    Sheets("ArtTable").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Processor List").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: As you wrote: This is too vague for a helpful answer.

Please provide relevant sections of the code you already have.

Comment: Sub UpdateProcessor()
'
' UpdateProcessor Macro
'

'
    ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Position:=xlLast
    Sheets("ArtTable").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Processor List").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Comment: Please add this to your answer (by editing your answer) and make sure the code is formatted correctly (using the Code Sample button in the edit window).

Comment: @HaukeP. I've been more of a visitor to Stackoverflow and most of the time finding answers to questions. Most of the questions I've asked are related to mysql. So....I am not sure what you mean by "add this" and "code formatted correctly" using the code sample

Comment: @benjo, [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31011600/edit) and include the code you just added.  Once the code is in there, select all the code and hit `CTRL+K` to format as a code block.  Check the preview to verify it looks correct.